# How can I get past the giant spider in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I can't seem to find any way to get to the chest.

Comment: Do you mean the one in the castle, that drops from the ceiling? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take off your weapon. If you don't harm his eggs, he won't crush you!